# Node Mongoose call methods on models from query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After querying for models i can't call a method on each.

```
     var mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
     Player          = mongoose.model('Player');

     Player.find({ controller : 'user' , 'timestamps.ai_last_spawned_at': { $lt: (Date.now() - settings.ai_spawn_interval) } }, function(err, players){

        if(err) throw err;

        console.info('Spawning AI for', players.length , 'players');

        _.each(players, function(player){

            player.spawnAi();

        });

    });
```

and in the schema i have:

```
    playerSchema.methods.spawnAi = function(options, cb){ }
```

The error i get is

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'spawnA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was due to me using Kue it only stored data of object (json.stringfy)